# Swift 'init()' is unavailable issue in Xcode 7.2 JSQMessages

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When I want to use init() JSQMessages there is an error like that. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: It solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no base init method [available](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.2.0/Classes/JSQMessage.html) for the JSQMessage class.

But we can see there's other inits available, like this one:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSenderId:(NSString *)senderId senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName date:(NSDate *)date text:(NSString *)text
```

Which in Swift is translated as:

```
JSQMessage(senderId: , displayName: , text: )
```

Another example for JSQMessagesBubbleImage in Objective-C:

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImage *bubbleImage = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImage alloc] initWithMessageBubbleImage: highlightedImage:];
```

It becomes:

```
let bubbleImage = JSQMessagesBubbleImage(messageBubbleImage: , highlightedImage: )
```